# Why there are 3 lines in all types of menu icons?

Tags: usability, icons, accessibility, menu, human-interface-guideline

I have noticed that all types of menu icons are using three lines or dots.
From a UI/UX perspective, does it matter the number of lines/dots?

[image]

For example if someone decides to use only one or six lines/dots would that be wrong?

[image]

Is there any rule/standart behind that?

Comment: It's conventional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides there're many posts claiming, it first appeared as representing a hamburger's meat inside 2 of it's breads as this [**link**](https://www.techjunkie.com/what-icon-with-three-lines-called/) states, I also believe (or naturally understand) it gives user the feeling there's a lot more to discover when clicked, since

> **"..."** punctuation has same meaning abstractly in grammar that
>   gives readers an understanding of sentence is continuing.

Besides I couldn't ran into any standart about this on any [**WCAG document**](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/menus/), using other than 3 lines/dots not necessarily gives the same experience like using a single or twice line/dot. ***And using more than 3 lines not desired I suppose since it's enough to emphasizing it with less.***